# Slidedown the div on hover of another div

Tags: jquery

I want to slidedown the nth div on hover of another div. I have made a function but it is not working. I want to slidedown on hover the child div of parent div on respective basis. With this function nothing is slidedown on hover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
  myfunction();
 
  });
  
  function myfunction(index) {
    var x = [];
    $(".check").each(function() {
       x.push($(this).text());
    });
    $("#demo1").text(x[0]); // We can use x[1 or 2 or 0] in the same id to get the value.
    $("#demo2").text(x[1]);
    $("#demo3").text(x[2]);
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide"</p>
<p class="check">button, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide" button</p>
</div>
<p id="demo1">"Hide" button</p>
<p id="demo2">"Hide"</p>
<p id="demo3">button</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you used such `hover` thing? I just see a `click` event. your question is not clear!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [`slideToggle`](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```js
var isShow = false;
$("#toggle").click(function(){
     $('.check').slideToggle();
     $(this).text(isShow? "Hide" : "Show");
     isShow = !isShow;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<div id="main">
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide"</p>
<p class="check">button, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide" button</p>
</div>
<p id="demo1">"Hide" button</p>
<p id="demo2">"Hide"</p>
<p id="demo3">button</p>
<button id="toggle">Hide</button>
```

If you still want to 2 buttons, you can try this way

```js
$("#hide").click(function(){
     $(".check").hide(500);
});

$("#show").click(function(){
     $(".check").show(500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide"</p>
<p class="check">button, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="check">If you click on the "Hide" button</p>
</div>
<p id="demo1">"Hide" button</p>
<p id="demo2">"Hide"</p>
<p id="demo3">button</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Comment: **1.** Where is the `hover` point? **2.** You removed a part of OP code, that change text.